# Xcode fetch keyboard plus suggestions height

Tags: swift, keyboard

I'm having an issue getting the correct height of the keyboard. It does not return the keyboard plus suggestions height.

Below is some sample code

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Then I have a utility method which returns keyboard frame from notification. Code looks like this

```
 var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
 var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
 if keyboardFrame.size.height <= 0 { // to fix bug on iOS 11
     keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
 }
 keyboardFrame = view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
```

The keyboard is not returning the keyboard height + suggestions

I require this as I'm doing some UI testing on iPhone 5 and on certain screens the keyboard clips the textfield. So I have this code to check if it overlaps

```
// fetches keyboard frame
let keyboardFrame = UtilityMethods.getKeyboardFrame(notification: notification, view: view)

let fieldFrame = lastNameField!.frame

// check if keyboard frame overlaps with field frame
if(keyboardFrame.intersects(fieldFrame)){    
   let newY = view.frame.origin.y - (fieldFrame.origin.y - keyboardFrame.height)
   UtilityMethods.animateViewMoving(viewToAnimate: view, newYValue: newY)
}
```

But because it is not returning the height of the keyboard + suggestions, the if statement fails. The only way this works is if I select another text field while keyboard is open, that then becomes first responder, then it returns keyboard height properly.

You can see when I print out the keyboard height

So when select fextfield, this height is printed out

```
216.0
```

Then if I select second text field, this height is then printed out

```
253.0
```

How do I make sure I'm always getting the keybaord height that includes the suggestions?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which notifications are you listening to?

Comment: Standard keyboard notifications. Included it in latest edit

Comment: Try listening to keyboardwillchangeframe as well, calling the same keyboardWillBeShown method.

Comment: No luck. WillChangeFrame seems to function the same way so having same issue. DidChange frame just causes strange behavior when keyboard dismisses. It tries animating keyboard back up again on dismiss.

Comment: Oh hang on - you're using the begin frame. You want the end frame, since that's the final keyboard size

Comment: Makes no difference, tried both